# Format a date so it can be written into Oracle ("Not a valid month" error)

Tags: c#, oracle, date

Having trouble with finding the proper syntax for this.  Here's my field on the ASP side:

```
<input type="text" id="EI_Open_AuditStartDt" class="datepicker" runat="server" 
    name="EI_Open_AuditStartDt" value='<%#Eval("Audit_Start_Date") %>' 
    style="width: 100px" />
```

Here's part of my code-behind in C#:

```
HtmlInputText EI_Open_AuditStartDt = (HtmlInputText)DataGrid_Open.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("EI_Open_AuditStartDt");
TextBox EI_Open_TransCIT = (TextBox)DataGrid_Open.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("EI_Open_TransCIT");

string StartDt = String.Format("{0:dd-mmm-yyyy}", EI_Open_AuditStartDt.Value);
string TransCIT = EI_Open_TransCIT.Text;

DataGrid_RootCauses.EditIndex = -1;

OracleConnection conn = GetConnection();
try
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("CST_AMR_WRITE_OPENSTATUS", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("v_StartDt", OracleType.DateTime).Value = StartDt;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("v_TransCIT", OracleType.VarChar).Value = TransCIT;
```

The problem is, when it gets to string StartDt, it still sees the value as, say, "03/24/2017" instead of "24-MAR-17", so I'm getting the "Not a valid month" error.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that the stored procedure is taking a string rather than a date argument.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Wouldn't it say not a valid date instead of month? You're most likely right either way because it says `OracleType.DateTime` and theres a string being inserted (can't be good?)

Comment: Well, this makes sense.  So how would I format that properly so it can be passed as a date?

Comment: I'd suggest using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: As I understand error raised from Oracle DB, it means that oracle `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` differs from `dd-mmm-yy`. if have access to oracle procedure you can set there `execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format = ''dd-mmm-yy''';` this command , or you can execute it from client side in the same session, or change string literal format to db format. I guess your DB format is `DD/MM/YY`.

Comment: I can confirm the Oracle data type is "DATE".  So, if anyone knows the correct syntax to use to convert a value in C#/ASP from MM/DD/YYYY to the proper format in Oracle, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify the format of the data stored in the Oracle DB.
2. Attempt to insert the data as a raw string, in that format and see if it succeeds.

That takes your calling code out of the possible variables affecting your problem.

3. If that still doesn't work, you have to look at the stored procedure and figure out if it's converting formats without your knowledge.
4. If you don't have the ability to see the stored procedure, you are going to have to try a bunch of different formats in your calling code until you find the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest inserting the value using [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format - i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
var StartDt = Date.ParseExact(EI_Open_AuditStartDt.Value,"dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture););
//.....
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("v_StartDt", OracleType.DateTime).Value = StartDt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Although, there is a good chance that you could do away with the date formatting in the param add, and simply hand it the `StartDt` object.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("v_StartDt", OracleType.DateTime).Value = StartDt;
```

Answer (score 0):

format in C# `var StartDt = Date.FormatExact(EI_Open_AuditStartDt.Value, "DD/MM/YY");` or if to be exact to format of your `database nls_date_format`.

Or you can use c# DateTime  and do following , note that function returns bool, you can check it in `if` operator and then assign `myDTvar` to command parameter.

`DateTime myDTvar;
DateTime.TryParseExact(StartDt, "dd-mmm-yyyy", null, 
                                   DateTimeStyles.None, out myDTvar)`

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, and it worked:

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(EI_Open_SubmissionDt.Value);
var SubDt = String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", dt1);
```

Would anyone with more C#/Oracle experience than I (which is pretty much everyone) care to poke holes in it?  Is this a legitimate answer, or are there potential issues with it?